# When does $S_n$ have exactly one subgroup of index $2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

When $n\geq 5$ we can assume there is another one besides $A_n$, they are both normal, so the intersection is normal in $S_n$ and also in $A_n$, contradicting that $A_n$ is simple.

For $n=1$ it's trivial it is false, for $n=2$ it's trivial it is true, for $n=3$ the order of such a subgroup would be three, by cauchy it has a $3$-cycle, and if it does it is $\{(123),(132),e\}$

I'm just missing $S_4$, I think I did it before, but I would appreciate a clean and as slick as possible approach. (If you have to use advanced stuff to make it slicker I'd like it even more :p)

Thank you very much in advance

Regards.

Comment: Re the first line, your proof is incomplete: if $H$ is another normal subgroup in $S_n$ of index two that is not trivial $H\cap A_n$ is normal in $A_n$. If $n>4$, this forces either $H\cap A_n=1$ or $H\cap A_n=A_n$. In the first case this cannot happen by cardinality considerations. It follows the second is true, $H\lhd A_n$, so $H=A_n$.

Comment: I was actually implicitly using Timbuc's lemma which says the intersection of a sub of $S_n$ with $A_n$ can have either half the elements of the sub or all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove the following

**Lemma:** Let $\;H\le S_n\;$ , then either $\;H\le A_n\;$ or else

$$\;\left|H\cap A_n\right|=\frac{|H|}2$$

The above means that in the second possibility exactly half the elements of $\;H\;$ are even permutations.

Comment: ok, I know that lemma, so then we assume exactly half are there, so we get $6$ even permutations, so then we get a subgroup of order $6$ of $A_4$. This doesn't exist, how would you prove that?

Comment: Is that how the proof goes? Am I right the contradiction is in that $A_4$ would have a sub of order $6$?

Comment: For $\;A_4\;$ yes, for all other $\;n>4\;$ not since $\;S_3\;$ can be embedded in $\;A_5\;$ . In fact, $\;S_n\;$ can be embedded in $\;A_{n+2}\;$

Comment: yeah, I meant $A_4$, all the other cases are covered. How would you prove $A_4$ has no sub of order $6$ as slick as possible?

Comment: And I didn't meant about a subgroup of order six or whatever, but about simplicity of $\;A_n\;,\;\;n\ge 5\;$ .

Comment: yeah, I answered all orders except $4$ in my original post, I just need $S_4$.

Comment: @JorgeFernández, perhaps showing that a subgroup generated by an element of order two and one of order three in $\;A_4\;$ is, after some calculations, already too big (because, clearly, there is no element of order six in $\;A_4\;$)

Comment: @JorgeFernández Read theorem 1 here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/A4noindex2.pdf It's as easy and elementary a proof as you can expect, imo.

Comment: That's perfect. That's really all that was missing, could you just write that in your solution? A normal subgroup of $S_4$ would have all the odd permutations, so it would have all the elements of $A_4$, and no others.

Comment: In fact that solution is great, you don't even need normality, you just need that half of the elements of $S_n$ are of odd order, which is really simple.

Comment: @JorgeFernández Well, you do *need* normality of the group $\;N\;$ in that theorem 1 for the quotient group $\;G/N\;$ to exist.

Comment: yeah, you need the normality of $N$, but not of $A_n$

Comment: I'll accept your answer, although what I needed is what is in the link, what is currently in the answer text I didn't help that much. But that link is awesome, thanks.